# SAPUI5 Stable ID's for Runtime Adaptation

Tags: sapui5

I trying to build an Application like this [RTA Demo App](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/rta/RuntimeAdaptationDemoAppMD.html?sap-rta-mock-lrep=true#/SalesOrders/5001656), but getting the following error:

`Generated id attribute found - to offer flexibility a stable control id is needed to assign the changes to, but for this control the id was generated by SAPUI5 __xmlview0--smartForm--GroupContactData`

```
<smartForm:SmartForm 
    id="SmartFormSalesOrder"
    title="Sales Order Details"
    editTogglable="true"
    editable="true"
    entityType="myType">                   
    <smartForm:Group
        id="GroupGeneralData"
        label="{i18n>smartFormGroup1}">

        <smartForm:GroupElement 
            id="GroupElementGeneralDataType">
            <smartField:SmartField value="{value1}" />
        </smartForm:GroupElement>

        <smartForm:GroupElement 
            id="smartForm--GroupElementGeneralDataSoldToParty">
            <smartField:SmartField value="{value2}" />
        </smartForm:GroupElement>

        <smartForm:GroupElement 
            id="smartForm--GroupElementGeneralDataAddressStreet">
            <smartField:SmartField value="{value3}" />
        </smartForm:GroupElement>

        <smartForm:GroupElement 
            id="smartForm--GroupElementGeneralDataAddressCity">
            <smartField:SmartField value="{value4}" />
        </smartForm:GroupElement>

        <smartForm:GroupElement 
            id="smartForm--GroupElementGeneralDataAddressZipCode">
            <smartField:SmartField value="{value5}" />
        </smartForm:GroupElement>

    </smartForm:Group>
 </smartForm:SmartForm>
```

The problem is that the ID's are prefixed by SAPUI5 and I do not know how I can prevent. The SAPUI5 Framework checks every ID if there are two underscore at the beginning of the ID and if its so, the Framework raises the "Generated id attribute found" Exception. So my questsion is: How can I make my own prefix as in Example App ("RTADemoAPPMD").

Answer (score 0):

I had to define a ID for the View where my Smartform is. The ID i had to define in the routing of the Component and not in the XML of my View